# How do I fix ToDoList is not in main.models in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, web-development-server

So when I do

```
>>>ToDoList.objects.all()

 I get
```

<QuerySet [<ToDoList: ufrz's list>]>

But when I do

```
>>>ToDoList.objects.get(id=1)

I get 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ufrz9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ufrz9\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 435, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
main.models.ToDoList.DoesNotExist: ToDoList matching query does not exist.
```

How do I get the id=1 command to work, I'm trying ultimately have it so when I do /ufrz's list I get my item and todolist

Comment: Apparently you don't have a row in your database where the value of the `id` column is equal to `1`.

Comment: Yes but when you create the first list it automatically defaults to id 1 that is why I am trying to figure out why it is not recognizing it.

Comment: Where do you see that it "automatically defaults to id 1"? What does `ToDoList.objects.all().first().id` give you, for example?

Comment: Oh wow, nevermind, for some reason I was under the impression that since it was the only List I thought it would go to 1, thank you Selcuk!

Comment: No, it is the value of the `id` column in your database. It might be anything depending on how many times you created and deleted rows from it. If you want to get the _first_ item in a queryset just use `.first()`.